# What are the best real time operating systems when security is required?

Tags: security, operating-system, real-time

I could build this non exhaustive list of RTOS : VxWorks, QNX, LynxOS, eCOS, WindowsCE, LinuxRT, Micrium, PURE, MMLite, XPembedded, RTAI, xenomai, Integrity, Nucleus, ThreadX.

From what I know, probably WxWorks and LynxOS are the best choice when security is required ([ISO 15408](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50341)). On the other hand, I worked recently on a Linux setup with "PREEMPT RT" set in the kernel for an embedded system. This setup had signed boot-loader, kernel, system and applications, with cryptographic keys in a TPM. Ok, this is just to provide you the context and where I am in my research.

My question is : Is there a recent survey of RTOS solutions, security centric ? Alternatively, what are your choices, why and for which usage?

Comment: I thought NSA had made a big effort to provide a secure version of Linux.  I don't have a reference.

Comment: Yes, **SELinux**. Thanks to point it out. There is an interresting discussion on it [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42383/how-trustworthy-is-selinux).